# How implement logical replication in postgres database with pg_rewind

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

How implement logical replication in postgres database with pg_rewind ?

wal_level = replica

I have used replica instead of logical and took basebackup in replica server , In acrchive server everytime i need to rename data file to data_old and again i need to took basebackup ,

How to use pg_rewind instead of basebackup ?

How to use pg_rewind instead of basebackup ?

Answer (score 0):

The pg_rewind utility can only be used in the streaming/physical replication setup. However if you want to need more insight on how to use the pg_rewind utility, I suggest you look at these docs [Documentation: 15: pg_rewind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.html), [PostgreSQL pg_rewind](https://www.tutorialdba.com/2017/11/postgresql-pgrewind.html).